# Print List items Containing all Character of a given word

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance

The Output should be only: rabbit and bibe but im getting it wrong all in the list is printing because last index has 'b' as well how can i print the specified element that contain only 'bib'

```js
let str = 'bib'
let list = ['rabbit', 'bibe', 'bundle']
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < list[i].length; j++) {
    let foundIndex = str.indexOf(list[i][j]) > -1
    if (foundIndex === -1) {
      list.splice(foundIndex, 1)
    } else if (foundIndex) {
      console.log(list[i])
    }
  }
}
```

Expecting Output should be:

```
rabbit
bibe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution, if we sort the letters "bib" becomes "bbi".

If we do a similar thing with the list ["rabbit","bibe","bundle"] becomes ["abbirt", "bbei" and "bdelnu"]. If we filter the letters not in "bib" the list shrinks to ["bbi","bbi","b"]. What we can now do is check for the occurrences of "bbi" in the resultant list.

Here's an intermediate implementation of the above:

```js
let str = 'bib';
let list = ['rabbit','bibe','bundle'];
let str2 = [...str].sort().join('');
let result =list.filter( function (w) {
    let w2 = [...w].filter( c => str.indexOf(c) !== -1 ).sort().join('');
    return w2.indexOf(str2) !== -1;
} );
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Here's the same code but golfed some more:

```js
let str = 'bib';
let list = ['rabbit','bibe','bundle'];
let result = list.filter( w => [...w].filter( c => str.indexOf(c) !== -1 ).sort().join('').indexOf([...str].sort().join('')) !== -1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be counting the number of each unique character in the given string and then filter the elements base on that: If an element has all of those characters, each with the same or higher amount, then it should be kept.

First, declare a helper function:

```js
function stringToMap(string) {
  return [...string].reduce((map, char) => {
    map[char] = map[char] + 1 || 1;
    return map;
  }, {});
}
```

It will return an object that looks like this:

```js
{
  b: 2,
  i: 1
}
```

`Array` objects have a very convenient method named [`.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which returns `true` if and only if the callback function returns true for all elements. We want to make use of it, so we convert the object above to an array of key-value pairs using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
const charsAndAmount = Object.entries(stringToMap(str));

// The object above now looks like this:
[
  ['b', 2],
  ['i', 1]
]
```

We do the same for each element of the list (not the `Object.entries()` part; we don't need their `.every()`):

```js
const charMaps = list.map(stringToMap);

[
  { r: 1, a: 1, b: 2, i: 1, t: 1 },
  { b: 2, i: 1, e: 1 },
  { b: 1, i: 1, k: 1, e: 1 },
  { b: 1, u: 1, n: 1, d: 1, l: 1, e: 1 }
]
```

This is the tricky part: For every word in the list, we check if it contains every character in the given string, each with the same or higher amount. If it does, `.every()` will return `true` and [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) will keep the word in the new list:

```js
const output = list.filter(
  (_, index) => charsAndAmount.every(
    ([char, number]) => number <= charMaps[index][char]
  // [ 'b',      2]       2    <=
  //           ({ r: 1, a: 1, b: 2, i: 1, t: 1 })['b']
  // 2 <= 2 === true
  )
);
```

Try it:

```js
function stringToMap(string) {
  return [...string].reduce((map, char) => {
    map[char] = map[char] + 1 || 1;
    return map;
  }, {});
}

const str = 'bib';

const charsAndAmount = Object.entries(stringToMap(str));

const list = ['rabbit', 'bibe', 'bike', 'bundle'];

const charMaps = list.map(stringToMap);

const output = list.filter(
  (_, index) => charsAndAmount.every(
    ([char, number]) => number <= charMaps[index][char]
  )
);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve this with the help of [`Array.every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method which tests whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function. It returns a `Boolean` value.

Live Demo **:**

```js
let str = 'bib'
let list = ['rabbit','bibe','bundle']
for(let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
  const allMatched = str.split('').every(e => list[i].indexOf(e) !== -1);
  if (allMatched) {
    console.log(list[i]);
  }
}
```

Updated answer as per the author comment **:**

```js
let str = 'bib';
let list = ['rabbit','bibe','bundle'];

const res = list.map(e => {
    return e.split('').filter(c => str.includes(c)).join('').length
});

res.forEach((matchedLength, index) => {
    if (matchedLength >= 3) {
    console.log(list[index])
  }
})
```

Comment: hi thank you for your answer but there still bug on it if i will run the element that only contains  'bi' it will still print example the list of array is = ['rabit','bie','bundlei'] this result will still print that not equal to str = 'bib'

Comment: @Scaplog Yeah you are right. I missed that somehow. Thanks for pointing that out. I will have a look and correct the logic.

Comment: @Scaplog I added one more code snippet as per the improvement. Can you please have a look and test the positive and negative scenarios and confirm.